# upload_to value changes photo.name attribute

Tags: python, django

Why is it that `upload_to` value changes the value of `photo.name`? I am trying to create a album directory during runtime and story my image within the appropriate album directory. My code is able to create a directory with the appropriate album name and has the correct photo in it but it changes `self.photo.name` to the `upload_to` value.

In the picture below. With the admin interface, I create an album called `test4` and I choose to upload `tumblr_nh09woLkmb1sfie3io1_1289.jpg`. `self.photo.name` will have the value of `test4/tumblr_nh09woLkmb1sfie3io1_1289.jpg`.

In my `upload_path` method I also tried

```
   return instance.album.title
   return '/' + instance.album.title
   return instance.album.title + '/'
```

this would NOT create a directory with the name of `instance.album.title` but instead save within my `MEDIA_ROOT` the file with the name of what the `upload_path` method returns. NOT the actual file name.

I feel as though the expected self.photo.name should be the name of the photo uploaded. In this case `tumblr_nh09woLkmb1sfie3io1_1289.jpg`

[image]

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin
from PIL import Image
from django.conf import settings
import os.path
from django.utils.html import format_html
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
import re


class Album(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def images(self):
        lst = [x.photo for x in self.photo_set.all()]
        return lst

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # super(Album, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        rgx = re.search(r'.*\w', self.title)
        self.title = rgx.group(0).replace(" ", "_")
        super(Album, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class AlbumAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ["title"]
    list_display = ["images"]

def upload_path(instance, filename):
    if " " in instance.album.title:
        instance.album.title.replace(" ", "_")
    return '/'.join([instance.album.title, filename])

class Photo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_path)
    upload = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def size(self):
        return "%s x %s" % (self.photo.width, self.photo.height)

    def thumbnail(self):
        thumbnail_html = "<a href=\"{0}{1}\"><img border=\"0\" alt=\"\" src=\"{2}{3}\" height=\"40\" /></a>".format(settings.MEDIA_URL, self.photo.name, settings.MEDIA_URL, self.photo.name)
        print settings.MEDIA_URL, settings.MEDIA_ROOT
        return thumbnail_html

    thumbnail.allow_tags = True

class PhotoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ["title", "photo"]
    list_display = ["photo", "thumbnail", "title", "album", "size"]
    list_filter = ["album"]
```

Comment: Try `os.path.join([...])`

Comment: @Cloudream not sure how this will help. Could you elaborate please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have in settings:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "../media_root/Boothie/pics") 
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

so whenever you pass `upload_to` to a `FileField` or an `ImageField` a path or a function, it will save in database in format `string_passed_to_upload_to/filename.ext` or the whole name generated by a  function passed to it. This way it is possible to recreate full path to the file: `MEDIA_ROOT + instance.photo.name` and url as well: `MEDIA_URL + instance.photo.name`. It is not the exact code from django, but just to give you an idea. Does it make sense? I can elaborate more on it with some examples.

**Edit**

If you want to be able to get just the base file name you can do `os.path.split(photo.name)[1]`. But no matter what, FileField will store file name in database relevant to the `MEDIA_ROOT` path.
You can also checkout [django-smartfields](https://github.com/lehins/django-smartfields) app, it has that property set, so if you have a model:

```
from smartfields import fields

def upload_path(instance, filename):
    if " " in instance.album.title:
        instance.album.title.replace(" ", "_")
    return '/'.join([instance.album.title, filename])

class Photo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album)
    photo = fields.ImageField(upload_to=upload_path, keep_orphans=True)
    upload = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

You than can use it like that: `photo.photo.name_base`. Make sure you pass to the field `keep_orphans=True`, otherwise it will remove old files.

Comment: I understand what youre saying but I am wondering how I can prevent the filename from being changed to `string_passed_to_upload_to/filename.ext`.

Comment: Just don't pass `upload_to` keyword, but then it will save it directly in the `MEDIA_ROOT` directory.

Comment: I wanted to sort the photos I am passing by their their album names. That is why I included `album.title` in the `upload_path` function

Comment: If you don't care that they are saved in the `MEDIA_ROOT`, you can skip the `upload_to` kwarg and retrieve `Photo` instances sorted like that: `Photo.objects.order_by('album__title', 'photo')`

Comment: I do care that it is saved in `MEDIA_ROOT` but something along the lines of `MEDIA_ROOT/album_name/file.jpeg` This way the files I upload are sorted by their album. I believe this is a convenient way to store custom uploaded photos  =D

Comment: That's cool. So why exactly do you want `photo.photo.name` give you `tumblr_nh09woLkmb1sfie3io1_1289.jpg` instead of `test4/tumblr_nh09woLkmb1sfie3io1_1289.jpg`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your questions. But say the photo is named `pic.jpg`. I created an album named `album1`. I basically want `pic.jpg` to be uploaded to `MEDIA_ROOT/album1`. My code currently creates the `album1` directory and places `pic.jpg` in that directory. However, in my `list_display = ["photo, ...."]`, `album1/pic.jpg` is displayed as the photo name when it is clearly not and I am not sure why it is causing this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70111/discussion-between-alexey-kuleshevich-and-liondancer).

Answer (score 1):

From the Django docs (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) about the `upload_to` function.

> A local filesystem path that will be appended to your MEDIA_ROOT setting to determine the value of the url attribute.

So if you specify `upload_to` as a function, Django will attempt to save the filename as a relative path to your `MEDIA_ROOT`.

Comment: So if `upload_to=some_func`. Django will attempt to save the file name as a relative path to my `MEDIA_ROOT`. What I am seeing right now is that Django is saving the file name as relative path to my uploaded file starting from the MEDIA_ROOT. For example, the file name will be named `album1/photo.jpg`. And the file will located in `media/root/album1/`. The location of the file is find but the filename will be `album1/photo.jpg`

Comment: What is your `MEDIA_ROOT` set to?

Comment: MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "../media_root/Boothie/pics")
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

Answer (score 1):

This May be helpful to you, use os.path.basename(self.file.name) instead of file.name in this example.

```
class FileModel(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="images/")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(os.path.basename(self.file.name))

    @property
    def filename(self):
        return str(os.path.basename(self.file.name))
```

Use file.url in your template file

Answer (score 1):

```
class Photo(models.Model):

    def upload_path(self, name):
        return '{0}/{1}'.format(
            self.album.title,
            name.lower().replace(' ', '_').encode('trans')
        )

    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_path)
```

So, if you define upload_to as a class method, you can operate by related object's field 'title', for example include it to the image path as sub directory.

Comment: Usually it is helpful to include some text which explains how the code answers the question or solves the problem in addition to bare code.